# Jenkins / GitHub trigger on Pull Request has error upon configuration

Tags: github, jenkins

I get the following error when trying to configure Jenkins to trigger off a GitHub Pull Request:

[image: StackTrace]

It is setup as follows:

[image: GitHub pull request section of job configuration]

I have researched a bit and have not found much to do with this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I have found was related to the cache size should be 0 of GitHub in the Jenkins Config in Manager. Also, there was something to do with the the GitHub project section of the job configuration was wrong. I have fixed both but still have errors.

Comment: I am also having the same problem when configuring the GitHub Branches Plugin.

Comment: Possibly related issue, though apparently a fix was released a few weeks back: https://github.com/KostyaSha/github-integration-plugin/issues/198